# Converter horas e minutos em minutos javascript

Tags: javascript

Eu preciso de um método que converta a hora e os minutos digitados no 
< input type="time" > pelo usuário em minutos.

ex: 01:35 retorne 95 minutos

é possivel realizar operações com esse input ?

Comment: Qual seria formato da data? 5h 2min ou 5:02 no input?

Comment: o formato da hora digitado no input type=time
5:02 e retornasse o valor 302

Comment: Já respondi. Se funciona me avisa.

Comment: Valeu mestre era exatamente isso que eu estava precisando!  :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solução para o problema:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="time" id="data">
        <button onclick="minutes()">Result</button>
        <p id="value"></p>
        <script>
            var data = document.getElementById("data");
            var value = document.getElementById("value");
            function minutes() {
                let f0 = data.value.split(":");
                value.innerHTML = ((Number(f0[0])*60)+Number(f0[1])) + " Minutes";
                return 0;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```